# Different results between IMAP request

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail, imap, email-client

My team and I coded a mail component to be used by other teams in our application. This component is designed to allow them to download emails using custom search conditions. The one that is being used at the moment is a mail search between a range of dates from Gmail accounts using [IMAP protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501). It was working properly until April 4th 2016 6:00AM GMT+1, only downloading email within the range. However, since 8:00AM GMT+1, the response from the server suddenly changed and it started returning the whole INBOX folder!

Repeating the initial tests, we discovered that we were receiving the whole INBOX folder instead of those within the range. After some research down to the IMAP request, it seemed that Gmail changed the amount of emails returned under certain conditions:

- When the "start date" `SearchTerm` had a `ComparisonTerm.GT` term, **or**
- When the "end date" `SearchTerm` had a `ComparisonTerm.LE` term

In both cases, Gmail's IMAP server returns all the emails in the folder. On the contrary, as an example, Yahoo's IMAP server just returns those emails which match the given condition.

We opened a ticket to them, asking if there was any change in their response, but they answered that they did not change anything. Of course, there is no way to prove it (we still don't have the time machine).

As we had a great impact with this unexpected behaviour, we decided to investigate further, and we created a simple mail client to download mail using different condition combinations from different IMAP servers.

Starting from [this link's](http://www.technicalkeeda.com/java/how-to-access-gmail-inbox-using-java-imap) program, we added the functionality to check with other, but changing the library to meet our javax.mail version 1.5.5. Therefore, we avoid different implementation behaviours.

The code is attached below:

```
package gmail;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.mail.search.AndTerm;
import javax.mail.search.ComparisonTerm;
import javax.mail.search.ReceivedDateTerm;
import javax.mail.search.SearchTerm;

public class JavaMailTest {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        JavaMailTest testClient=new JavaMailTest();
        
        //Yahoo
        //SEARCH SINCE 3-Apr-2016 BEFORE 7-Apr-2016 ALL
        testClient.performTest(testClient.getYahooImapProps(),ComparisonTerm.GE,ComparisonTerm.LT);
        //Gmail
        //SEARCH SINCE 3-Apr-2016 BEFORE 7-Apr-2016 ALL
        testClient.performTest(testClient.getGmailImapProps(),ComparisonTerm.GE,ComparisonTerm.LT);
        //Yahoo
        //SEARCH SINCE 3-Apr-2016 OR BEFORE 7-Apr-2016 ON 7-Apr-2016 ALL
        testClient.performTest(testClient.getYahooImapProps(),ComparisonTerm.GE,ComparisonTerm.LE);
        //Gmail
        //SEARCH SINCE 3-Apr-2016 OR BEFORE 7-Apr-2016 ON 7-Apr-2016 ALL
        testClient.performTest(testClient.getGmailImapProps(),ComparisonTerm.GE,ComparisonTerm.LE);
        //Yahoo
        //SEARCH NOT ON 3-Apr-2016 SINCE 3-Apr-2016 BEFORE 7-Apr-2016 ALL
        testClient.performTest(testClient.getYahooImapProps(),ComparisonTerm.GT,ComparisonTerm.LT);
        //Gmail
        //SEARCH NOT ON 3-Apr-2016 SINCE 3-Apr-2016 BEFORE 7-Apr-2016 ALL
        testClient.performTest(testClient.getGmailImapProps(),ComparisonTerm.GT,ComparisonTerm.LT);
        //Yahoo
        //SEARCH NOT ON 3-Apr-2016 SINCE 3-Apr-2016 OR BEFORE 7-Apr-2016 ON 7-Apr-2016 ALL
        testClient.performTest(testClient.getYahooImapProps(),ComparisonTerm.GT,ComparisonTerm.LE);
        //Gmail
        //SEARCH NOT ON 3-Apr-2016 SINCE 3-Apr-2016 OR BEFORE 7-Apr-2016 ON 7-Apr-2016 ALL
        testClient.performTest(testClient.getGmailImapProps(),ComparisonTerm.GT,ComparisonTerm.LE);

    }

    public int performTest(Properties props, int startTermCondition, int endTermCondition)
    {
        try {
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            Message[] totalMessages = null;

            Store store = session.getStore(props.getProperty("protocol"));
            store.connect(props.getProperty("mail.imap.host"), props.getProperty("account"), props.getProperty("pass"));
            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("inbox");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);


            SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
            Date startDate = ft.parse("2016-04-03");
            Date endDate = ft.parse("2016-04-07");

            System.out.println("Testing email account: <"+props.getProperty("account")+"> with startDate: <" + startDate + "> (ComparisonTerm."+
                    getConditionText(startTermCondition)+") and endDate: <" + endDate+"> (ComparisonTerm."+getConditionText(endTermCondition)+")");

            Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();

            if (messages != null && messages.length > 0) {
                SearchTerm startDateTearm = 
                        new ReceivedDateTerm(startTermCondition, startDate);

                SearchTerm endDateTerm = 
                        new ReceivedDateTerm(endTermCondition, endDate);

                SearchTerm andTerm = new AndTerm(startDateTearm, endDateTerm); 

                totalMessages = inbox.search(andTerm);
                if(totalMessages.length > 0){
                    System.out.println("Found "+totalMessages.length+" matching messages (Total messages in folder: "+messages.length+")");
                }

                /*for (int i = 0; i < totalMessages.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(totalMessages[i].getReceivedDate() + " --> Mail Subject:- " + totalMessages[i].getSubject());

                }*/
                //First message
                int currentMessage=0;
                System.out.println("First Message: "+totalMessages[currentMessage].getReceivedDate() + " --> Mail Subject: " + totalMessages[currentMessage].getSubject().substring(0, 5));
                //Last message
                currentMessage=totalMessages.length-1;
                System.out.println("Last Message:  "+totalMessages[currentMessage].getReceivedDate() + " --> Mail Subject: " + totalMessages[currentMessage].getSubject().substring(0, 5));
            }


            inbox.close(true);
            store.close();
            return totalMessages.length;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }

    }
    
    public static String getConditionText(int condition)
    {
        String returnValue="";
        switch (condition) {
        case ComparisonTerm.EQ:
            returnValue="EQ";
            break;
        case ComparisonTerm.GE:
            returnValue="GE";
            break;
        case ComparisonTerm.GT:
            returnValue="GT";
            break;
        case ComparisonTerm.LE:
            returnValue="LE";
            break;
        case ComparisonTerm.LT:
            returnValue="LT";
            break;
        case ComparisonTerm.NE:
            returnValue="NE";
            break;
        default:
            returnValue="Error";
            break;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
    
    public Properties getYahooImapProps()
    {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        //Yahoo
        String imapServer="imap.mail.yahoo.com";
        String imapPort="993";
        String account="********@yahoo.es";
        String pass="*********";
        
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.host", imapServer);
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.port", imapPort);
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.auth", "true");
        props.setProperty("account", account);
        props.setProperty("pass", pass);
        props.setProperty("protocol", "imaps");
        
        return props;
        
    }

    public Properties getGmailImapProps()
    {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        //Gmail
        String imapServer="imap.gmail.com";
        String imapPort="143";
        String account="******@gmail.com";
        String pass="********";
        
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.host", imapServer);
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.port", imapPort);
        /*props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.auth", "true");*/
        props.setProperty("account", account);
        props.setProperty("pass", pass);
        props.setProperty("protocol", "imap");
        
        return props;
    }

}
```

To make the program output clearer, I added the request right before the first method output:

```
  //SEARCH SINCE 3-Apr-2016 BEFORE 7-Apr-2016 ALL
  Testing email account: <*********@yahoo.es> with startDate: <Sun Apr 03 00:00:00 CEST 2016> (ComparisonTerm.GE) and endDate: <Thu Apr 07 00:00:00 CEST 2016> (ComparisonTerm.LT)
  Found 5 matching messages (Total messages in folder: 78)
  First Message: Mon Apr 04 23:14:22 CEST 2016 --> Mail Subject: Aviso
  Last Message:  Tue Apr 05 00:48:00 CEST 2016 --> Mail Subject: Alter
  //SEARCH SINCE 3-Apr-2016 BEFORE 7-Apr-2016 ALL
  Testing email account: <*********@gmail.com> with startDate: <Sun Apr 03 00:00:00 CEST 2016> (ComparisonTerm.GE) and endDate: <Thu Apr 07 00:00:00 CEST 2016> (ComparisonTerm.LT)
  Found 92 matching messages (Total messages in folder: 20138)
  First Message: Sun Apr 03 04:08:47 CEST 2016 --> Mail Subject: Tu es
  Last Message:  Wed Apr 06 22:12:45 CEST 2016 --> Mail Subject: ¿Quie
  //SEARCH SINCE 3-Apr-2016 OR BEFORE 7-Apr-2016 ON 7-Apr-2016 ALL
  Testing email account: <*********@yahoo.es> with startDate: <Sun Apr 03 00:00:00 CEST 2016> (ComparisonTerm.GE) and endDate: <Thu Apr 07 00:00:00 CEST 2016> (ComparisonTerm.LE)
  Found 5 matching messages (Total messages in folder: 78)
  First Message: Mon Apr 04 23:14:22 CEST 2016 --> Mail Subject: Aviso
  Last Message:  Tue Apr 05 00:48:00 CEST 2016 --> Mail Subject: Alter
  //SEARCH SINCE 3-Apr-2016 OR BEFORE 7-Apr-2016 ON 7-Apr-2016 ALL
  Testing email account: <*********@gmail.com> with startDate: <Sun Apr 03 00:00:00 CEST 2016> (ComparisonTerm.GE) and endDate: <Thu Apr 07 00:00:00 CEST 2016> (ComparisonTerm.LE)
  Found 20138 matching messages (Total messages in folder: 20138)
  First Message: Sat Sep 04 13:23:35 CEST 2004 --> Mail Subject: Gmail
  Last Message:  Tue Apr 19 10:09:06 CEST 2016 --> Mail Subject: El re
  //SEARCH NOT ON 3-Apr-2016 SINCE 3-Apr-2016 BEFORE 7-Apr-2016 ALL
  Testing email account: <*********@yahoo.es> with startDate: <Sun Apr 03 00:00:00 CEST 2016> (ComparisonTerm.GT) and endDate: <Thu Apr 07 00:00:00 CEST 2016> (ComparisonTerm.LT)
  Found 5 matching messages (Total messages in folder: 78)
  First Message: Mon Apr 04 23:14:22 CEST 2016 --> Mail Subject: Aviso
  Last Message:  Tue Apr 05 00:48:00 CEST 2016 --> Mail Subject: Alter
  //SEARCH NOT ON 3-Apr-2016 SINCE 3-Apr-2016 BEFORE 7-Apr-2016 ALL
  Testing email account: <*********@gmail.com> with startDate: <Sun Apr 03 00:00:00 CEST 2016> (ComparisonTerm.GT) and endDate: <Thu Apr 07 00:00:00 CEST 2016> (ComparisonTerm.LT)
  Found 20138 matching messages (Total messages in folder: 20138)
  First Message: Sat Sep 04 13:23:35 CEST 2004 --> Mail Subject: Gmail
  Last Message:  Tue Apr 19 10:09:06 CEST 2016 --> Mail Subject: El re
  //SEARCH NOT ON 3-Apr-2016 SINCE 3-Apr-2016 OR BEFORE 7-Apr-2016 ON 7-Apr-2016 ALL
  Testing email account: <*********@yahoo.es> with startDate: <Sun Apr 03 00:00:00 CEST 2016> (ComparisonTerm.GT) and endDate: <Thu Apr 07 00:00:00 CEST 2016> (ComparisonTerm.LE)
  Found 5 matching messages (Total messages in folder: 78)
  First Message: Mon Apr 04 23:14:22 CEST 2016 --> Mail Subject: Aviso
  Last Message:  Tue Apr 05 00:48:00 CEST 2016 --> Mail Subject: Alter
  //SEARCH NOT ON 3-Apr-2016 SINCE 3-Apr-2016 OR BEFORE 7-Apr-2016 ON 7-Apr-2016 ALL
  Testing email account: <*********@gmail.com> with startDate: <Sun Apr 03 00:00:00 CEST 2016> (ComparisonTerm.GT) and endDate: <Thu Apr 07 00:00:00 CEST 2016> (ComparisonTerm.LE)
  Found 20138 matching messages (Total messages in folder: 20138)
  First Message: Sat Sep 04 13:23:35 CEST 2004 --> Mail Subject: Gmail
  Last Message:  Tue Apr 19 10:09:06 CEST 2016 --> Mail Subject: El re
```

From this result we can say the following:

- Yahoo returns the proper amount of emails, considering the given Java conditions.
- Javamail's request is probably too ambiguous.
- @Gmail: given the bunch of conditions in some requests... why you just decide to return the whole folder?
- Why is there a different response for the same request?
- Who is returning mails right?
- Aren't protocols designed to standarise things instead of making it even worse?

We also tried with an Outlook account, with the same result as Gmail.

Comment: Protocols are generally designed to standardise, but that's not necessarily the only aim, and sometimes it's not the top priority. Sometimes it conflicts with simplicity of implementation, and loses. In the case of date searches IMAP explicitly doesn't specify timezone handling, so if the SINCE limit differs by a few hours among servers, that's permitted. Of course that's not what you're seeing: I only offer a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sure looks like a bug in Gmail to me.  I was able to reproduce it myself.  I'm really surprised if Outlook.com has the same bug.

Why do you think the request is ambiguous?  The IMAP spec is pretty clear.

A few notes...

- Are you sure you're using JavaMail 1.5.5?  The SEARCH commands you're showing reflect a [JavaMail bug](https://kenai.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6526) from before 1.5.3.
- You should [change Session.getDefaultInstance to Session.getInstance](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#getdefaultinstance).
- You [don't need the socket factory properties](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes); just set "mail.imap.ssl" to "true" instead.

Comment: I remember noticing that javamail OR and wondering what bug you were working around. And now I see it was a bug, not a workaround ;)

Comment: My contact at Google has confirmed that this is a Gmail bug, which will be fixed very soon.

Answer (score 0):

@BillShannon

I think @popilla20k sees the request ambiguous because when he makes a request with a "GT" **AND** "LE" searchTerm (andTerm), it is decomposed, for example, as:

//SEARCH SINCE 3-Apr-2016 **OR BEFORE** 7-Apr-2016 ON 7-Apr-2016 ALL

I must say I've seen a change in Google's behaviour on April 6. Days before, I retrieved all mails that satisfied the condition with "GT" AND "LE" searchTerm. After April 6, I see the same behaviour showed by @popilla20k (using javamail 1.5.5)

Even so, I think the clause **OR BEFORE** invalids the first one. Does it should be AND clause, isn't? Anyway, days before April 6 the same requests were answered differently than nowadays.

Thanks.

Comment: You misunderstand the IMAP SEARCH syntax.  OR is a prefix operator, applying to the two search terms that come after it - the BEFORE term and the ON term.  The OR term is combined with the SINCE term using the default AND operation for multiple search terms.

Comment: You're right. So, it's clear for me that we're dealing with a Google's IMAP bug. 
Thanks Bill.