# IMAP BEFORE search result is always empty with Office 365

Tags: java, office365, jakarta-mail, imap

I use this code to search through a Outlook 365 inbox programmatically:

```
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties());
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("outlook.office365.com", 993, EMAIL, PASSWORD);
Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
Message[] messages = emailFolder.search(new ReceivedDateTerm(LT,
        Date.from(Instant.now().minus(14, DAYS))));
```

Therefore an IMAP [BEFORE search](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3501.html#section-6.4.4) is performed e.g. `SEARCH BEFORE 16-Oct-2021 ALL`
but the returned `messages` array is always empty although there are thousands of mails older than 14 days. If a very short interval is used then there is a non-empty result.

Office 365 provides following capabilities

```
CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS MOVE ID UNSELECT CLIENTACCESSRULES CLIENTNETWORKPRESENCELOCATION BACKENDAUTHENTICATE CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
```

Are there any solutions and / or workaround to perform a server side search with dates like "older than" and "younger than" resp. using IMAP and Office 365 that works reliable?

Comment: Dumb question, but are you sure the messages haven’t been archived away to another folder?  Other than that ‘ALL’ is redundant, the search looks fine.

Comment: In my case `emailFolder.getMessages()` returns 49000+ messages and the majority of them are older than 14 days. I think it's similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/36697702 and I asked the community how others work with Office 365 via IMAP and searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a longer correspondence with Microsoft Office 365 support this bug has been finally fixed by the exchange server team and rolled out in the night of 2022-01-21 CET.
Now the IMAP `SEARCH BEFORE` command works as expected.

Additionally we found out that [`SENTBEFORE`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3501.html#page-52) and [`SENTSINCE`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3501.html#page-52) are properly supported and return fast results even for thousands of messages while other IMAP email provider take several minutes for a result and similar amount of messages. They are supported by [`SentDateTerm`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/docs/api/jakarta.mail/jakarta/mail/search/SentDateTerm.html) in [Jakara Mail](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/mail/) client.

While `BEFORE`, `ON` and `SINCE` refer to an unspecified **internal** date, use     `SENTBEFORE`, `SENTON` and `SENTSINCE` the actual [Date: header](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2822#section-3.6.1) of the message.